# Is it possible to pass a Knockout.JS variable into a onclick function WITHOUT binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to pass a Knockout.JS variable into an onclick function WITHOUT binding the function to the view model?

Below, i'm trying to pass the username parameter for the particular row below:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: viewModel">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: UserId"></td>
            <td><button onclick="alertRowName($element.UserName)"></button></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>

<script>
  function alertRowName(string){
    alert(string);
  }

//in my example the model is from a c# viewmodel..
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
var jsModel = ko.toJS(viewModel);    
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like this.
**EDIT**

hmmmm.. just noticed the Without binding.  Can you clarify why without binding?

```js
var app = Window.app || {};
app.model = [{
  UserId: 1,
  UserName: "User Name Here",
}];

app.ViewModel = function ViewModel(model){
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
};

app.ViewModel.prototype.alertRowName = function alertRowName(user) {
  alert(user.UserName());
};

ko.applyBindings(new app.ViewModel(app.model));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: UserId"></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click: $root.alertRowName, text: UserName"></button> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**BEWARE...HERE BE DRAGONS**

You can do the following, but I would strongly recommend not doing this.
This is attaching a function to the Window object making it a Global function.  each event handler generally has an event object available that you can use.

```js
var app = Window.app || {};
app.model = [{
  UserId: 1,
  UserName: "User Name Here",
}];

app.ViewModel = function ViewModel(model){
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
};

app.ViewModel.prototype.alertRowName = function alertRowName(user) {
  alert(user.UserName());
};

ko.applyBindings(new app.ViewModel(app.model));

Window.myButtonClick = function(){
  var item = ko.dataFor(event.currentTarget);
  alert(item.UserName());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: UserId"></td>
      <td><button onclick="Window.myButtonClick()" data-bind="text: UserName"></button> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: without binding would mean to make an onclick="javascriptfuction(KOvariable)" inside the button. Instead of binding the function to the viewmodel.

Comment: I have added some code that will do what you ask, though I strongly recommend against using it.  The advantage of the view-model approach is that it puts a container around the various functions you want that view model to act on.